# Cómo puedo crear un for loop para resumir algunas variables y dividirlas por algunos de sus valores con dcast()?

Tags: r, rstudio

a todos:
Tengo la siguiente base de datos, llamada prueba, con cinco variables:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero crear un ciclo for para agrupar los datos siempre con las dos primeras variables y con la tercera y cuarta variable en cada iteración. Para cada iteración, el bucle for debe sumar la variable ta para cada grupo. Además, para cada iteración el for loop debe crear una variable "id" que une la primera y la segunda variables y luego generar columnas con cada uno de los valores de la tercera y cuarta variables y la suma de la variable ta, en su respectiva iteracion. El problema es que la función dcast () me pide que inserte el nombre de la variable que quiero desagrupar sin comillas y cuando uso paste(), el nombre se pega con comillas. Esto no permite que la instrucción funcione correctamente. ¿Cómo podría solucionar esto? Inserto el código que he generado e imágenes de lo que quiero obtener:

```
for (i in 3:4) {
 hoy <-  prueba %>% group_by(cve_delegacion,cve_subdelegacion,prueba[,i]) %>% 
          summarise(total=sum(ta)) %>% unite("id", cve_delegacion, 
          cve_subdelegacion, sep = "")

 hoy <- hoy%>% dcast (id ~ paste (colnames (hoy[, 2])))
```

}

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usa la función `as.symbol` para remover las comillas al nombre.

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/memisc/versions/0.99.27.3/topics/as.symbols

Revisa esta otra función para hacer el unpivot, pudieras usar posiciones y olvidarte del nombre de la variable:

https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_wider.html

Finalmente, si sólo trabajarás con dos variables, no creo que amerite un `forloop` para ello. Solo haz cada uno de los casos, le estas agregando complejidad innecesaria al ejercicio.